# Scrolling a Kivy Label horizontally

Tags: python, kivy

I'd like to have a label in a kivy app scroll horizontally with a fixed vertical size rather than vertically with wrapping.  Imagine something like the marquee tag in the bad old days.

Eventually I'd like to have this automatically scroll left to right (and back) to show a string that is too long to display.

All of the scrollable label examples I've seen are vertically scrolling and two days of working on it has gotten me nowhere.

Edit:
Note: I am working on Windows for the time being.  The target will eventually be android and iphone

Here's an example of the UI I want...

[image: Example:]

The track name at the bottom should be the height of one line of the text and scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 2):

The same way of doing the vertical scroll:

```
ScrollView:
        Label:
            text: 'hellooooooooooooooooooooosdsadas'
            text_size: None, self.height  # Set the text wrap box height
            size_hint_x: None
            width: self.texture_size[0]  # Set the Label width to the text width
```

Result will be:

[image: scroll horizontal]

Comment: Are you running on windows?  In windows, fixing the height to one line and trying to scroll with this particular setup does not work for me.  Will test in other places once I setup builddozer...

Comment: I am running on ubuntu

Comment: For what it's worth...  My install was apparently corrupted.  Reinstalling Anaconda, Kivy, Cython 0.21x fixed the problem. Thanks.